# How are certain websites able to override the specific exitnode you chose, and can a fix be made to stop it?

Tags: network-configuration

I've followed the instructions in the posts about using a specific exitnode, and I've added the following to my torrc:

```
ExitNodes 719FD0FA327F3CCBCDA0D4EA74C15EA110338942
StrictNodes 1
```

As you can see, I've specified the exitnode by fingerprint rather than IP, which is 185.220.100.252

Now, this works fine when I go to http://www.duckduckgo.com or http://www.nasa.gov - I get that exact IP address.  However, certain websites like  https://ayefiles.com are somehow defeating this restriction, sending me to a different IP.  This breaks my use case, where I need (for a short amount of time) all accesses through the same exitnode.

Is this a security hole I have discovered, and if so, can we close it so such sites cannot hack my choice of exitnode?  Or, is it because StrictNodes 1 doesn't apply to ExitNodes and only ExcludeNodes?  If this is the problem, can someone tell me how to specify the same restriction using ExcludeNodes?  I.e. something like this:

```
ExcludeNodes !719FD0FA327F3CCBCDA0D4EA74C15EA110338942
StrictNodes 1
```

so I want to exclude all nodes BUT that specific fingerprint.  Is there a syntax for this???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`StrictNodes` does **not** apply to `ExitNodes`. This is declared in the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes).

> (StrictNodes applies to neither ExcludeExitNodes nor to ExitNodes).

Use `MapAddress` for doing that. Like this:

```
MapAddress ayefiles.com ayefiles.com.719FD0FA327F3CCBCDA0D4EA74C15EA110338942.exit
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work.  As when I use "ExitNodes" in the torrc file, MapAddress works for duckduckgo.com, but not ayefiles.com.  With your line in my torrc, and TOR restarted, opening ayefiles.com takes me to 176.9.53.58, and then 148.253.182.141 after doing a Ctrl+L (which ideally would be a no-op if my exit node is fixed).  Any other ideas?  

I noticed that you can't go to ayefiles.com by IP address - it's behind some sort of CloudFare protection.  Could that be related to the TOR malfunction?

Comment: I've filed a ticket with TOR, and done some follow up research.  The rabbit hole got deeper. https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/29989

Comment: You could take another look by asking Tor to build a certain circuit using [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html#custom-path-selection), if you are familiar with Python. BTW, Tor has a [`Log` torrc option](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en#Log) that allows you to specify a logging level (`debug` might be needed) and a filename.